# With webpack dev server, is it possible to watch files in an external dependency?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm working with multiple packages, let's call them WebApp and Utility. WebApp has a dependency on Utility, which lives locally via "npm link". I am using webpack-dev-server to run WebApp in the browser during development. I would like to modify files in the Utility package and see them reflected after a page refresh, but webpack-dev-server doesn't watch external files -- I have to kill and restart webpack-dev-server to see them.

Is it possible for webpack-dev-server to watch external files and reload them for me? I haven't been able to find any docs on a feature like this.

I'm on webpack 1.13.3 & webpack-dev-server 1.16.2. Not using hot module reloading, a full page refresh is sufficient. Thanks!

Comment: I am running into an error like this also with webpack 4 and webpack-dev-server 3.1.14. Some reproducible code here https://github.com/cmdcolin/webpack_dev_server_question